# Re-print same page with different dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

I have a 1-page daily task form that needs to be filled out every day.  I'd like to print off a whole months supply by dynamically changing the date field and re-printing every date in an entire range

```
  |  A           |   B        |
--|--------------|------------|
1 | Date         | 10/01/2018 |
2 | Clean Dishes | __________ |
3 | Clean Litter | __________ |
4 | Clean Floor  | __________ |
```

Right now, I'm just dragging the entire page down 31 times and printing each date individually, but that feels wrong.

Any way to do this, maybe with macros, [headers](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/print-headings-or-titles-on-every-page-96719bd4-b93e-4237-8f97-d2cabb1b196a), or mail-merge?

Didn't really find any answers here:

- [Increment date on printing each page](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/691103-increment-date-on-printing-each-page.html)
- [Printing multiple pages with ascending dates?](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/590421-priting-multiple-pages-ascending-dates.html)
- [How To Print Multiple Copies With Sequence Page Numbers?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4117-excel-print-multiple-copies-with-different-page-numbers.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick macro solution. Edit the start and end dates in the code.

```vb
Sub PrintAllDates()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim printDate As Date
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    startDate = "10/01/2018"
    endDate = "10/31/2018"
    For printDate = startDate To endDate
        ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = printDate
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```